# Setting Twilio Client customParameters on incoming call for conferences

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-taskrouter

I am currently using Twilio Client for all of our end points, and all of our call legs are being bridged by agent conferences.  Calls to Twilio Client are therefore made either by the Task Router 'conference' command on inbound calls, or the agent conference participant API.  I would like to provide my client application with more information about an incoming call such as with customParameters, but cannot find a way to pass additional information when using the conference interface to create calls.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a direct way to do that via Client customParameters. Are you using TaskRouter.js as well? Could you pass the information via attributes on the task instead?

Comment: I'm not using task router in the client, but that might be a better solution.  For now I have been using sync to pass data such as incoming calls to the client.

Comment: I'd take a look at [TaskRouter.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/integrate-browser-based-application) as that will more closely tie your call data to the tasks and the agent in the browser. Sync is good for that, but TaskRouter.js will just tighten up the relationships.